# Python-IDLE editor syntax coloring sometimes stopped working

Tags: ide, python-idle

While editing a python file, IDLE is normally changing the color of special python word, change the colors of commented line, and the color of strings.
All according to the color-map, (as any code-editor will do).

My problem is that sometimes after I edit the file, this color changing stop working.
So commenting (or uncommenting) a line, will leave the line colors as is.  (Frustration comment: it is very annoying to find out the BUG you are working on is only due a line that you thought is in a comment but it isn't)

I have two bad solutions to this problem, and I hope to find one good solution.

First bad solution is reopening the file, but it is a very bad solution, cause the color change is essential for ongoing development, and I can't always reopen each file.

My second solution is to stop working with IDLE, this is also bad, cause I like the simplicity of IDLE for quick and simple coding tasks.

This happened to me on a Windows and a Linux machine

[Edited Windows Tk version]

- Windows python version 2.7.10 and Tk version 8.5.15
- Linux python version 2.7.11+ and Tk version 8.6.5

Comment: I (IDLE maintainer) don't remember seeing this or a previous report like this.  I hope it is not due to the new tk 8.6.5.  Can you make this happen 'on-demand'?  It is terribly hard to fix occasional random failures.  Python.org distributes 2.7.10/11 with tk 8.5.15.  How did you get that python with 8.6.5?  Are you running IDLE from icon or console (`python -m idlelib.idle`)?  If the former, try the latter and see if any error messages appear on the console.  It would be nice to know if you would see same problem with, say, 3.5 on the same machine.

Comment: On thing I have seen with long files (say over 3000 lines) is that there is a noticeable delay in recoloring a file after making an option change (new font, new size, new theme) that requires the text to be rewritten.  But even then, the delay is usually less than a second.

Comment: **1st comment:** I fixed a mistake in my windows TK version, it is 8.5.15, and the problem is the same in win and linux with the 8.6.5.
I'll try to make this happen 'on-demand' and if it'll work I will post it here.
I'm running it only **from icon**, I tried now the console line, and there was no error message. currently I'm not using 3.5 at all.
**2nd comment:** the files I edit are very short never reaching 300 lines, and the problem is in the normal file editing and not in changing some visual preferences.

Comment: What color scheme are you using?  The default? What is the exact symptom?  Do colors disappear and everything becomes black and white, or do they simple stay as they are when they should change?  Do you enter non-ascii chars?  Does problem appear with normal letters, or when entering a special char?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, default color scheme, the exact symptom is they simple stay as they are when they should change. More accurate, only when commenting/ uncommenting a line, the color should be Red, ,or other, and it is not changing. I'm not using non-ascii chard (not intentionally..), the problem appear when inserting # or deleting #.

Comment: Found it!, while playing with it a bit, I was trying to comment and uncomment some lines, to get the problem to happen again. and because my normal IDE is pycharm I was using keyboard shortcut CTRL+/ , pressing this shortcut will freeze any color changes on the screen, until I press CTRL+/ again. I tried to check what this key combination is doing, and found this: force-open-calltip, not sure what it is.

Comment: Open Calltips is bound to ^\, not ^/.  The latter is bound to 'toggle-auto-coloring', which is exactly what you observed.  The 'bug' is that this is extremely hard to discover -- no menu entry, no doc entry, no status bar indicator -- just the alphabetical entry in the Keys listing.  I opened https://bugs.python.org/issue27170 to either remedy the deficiencies or remove the option.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your effort.

Comment: To me, calltips are extremely useful -- a callable signature and line of he docstring.  See '2.3. Calltips' in the current doc.  They popup automatically if one types `function_expession(` and waits for the configured delay (default 2 seconds, but I use 0).  'Force open' is used when one has already typed past '(', or is debugging a completed call that caused an exception.

Comment: This issue also reinforces my previous idea that it should be possible to get a reverse listing mapping key to action, so you could have looked up '<Control-Key-slash>' in an alphabetical key listing.  Anyway, thanks for following up until you found the reproducible cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IDLE there is a hidden key combination `CTRL-/`, that toggles Auto Coloring. Currently there is no way to disable it, for more information see this [bugs.python.org/issue27170](http://bugs.python.org/issue27170).

I post this answer after investigation this issue with @terry-jan-reedy in the question comments.

The reason I used `CTRL-/` in the first place is because of habit from using PyCharm - which is used for *comment a line*.